# Targeting the text of a span inside a clicked table row button

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table that contains some data and it looks like this

```
 <tr data-v-0a4de454="">
            <td data-v-0a4de454=""><span data-v-0a4de454="" id="one">KIng Room</span> <span data-v-0a4de454="" class="badge badge-primary">apartment</span></td>
            <td data-v-0a4de454="" id="two">2</td>
            <td data-v-0a4de454="">
                KES <span data-v-0a4de454="" id="three">7,171</span><br data-v-0a4de454="" />
                <b data-v-0a4de454="">Includes taxes and charges</b><br data-v-0a4de454="" />
                <span data-v-0a4de454="" class="badge bg-green">Getaway Deal</span>
            </td>
            <td data-v-0a4de454="">
                <ul data-v-0a4de454="" class="vh">
                    <li data-v-0a4de454="">Total cost to cancel</li>
                    <li data-v-0a4de454=""><b data-v-0a4de454="">NO PREPAYMENT NEEDED</b> pay at the property</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td data-v-0a4de454="">
                <div data-v-0a4de454="" class="input-group mb-3">
                    <select data-v-0a4de454="" class="custom-select">
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" selected="selected">Select Rooms</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="1">1</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="2">2</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="3">3</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="4">4</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="5">5</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="6">6</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="7">7</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="8">8</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="9">9</option>
                        <option data-v-0a4de454="" value="10">10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td data-v-0a4de454=""><button data-v-0a4de454="" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button></td>
        </tr>
```

and like this on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5m7v0ugo/1/

I want to get the value of the span of text with the id one and this is what i have tried and returns blank

```
  alert($(this).closest('td').find('#one').text());
  alert($(this).parents('tr').find('#one').text());
```

I want to get the values of the elements with id one, two and three.

I am running the code on click and i have attached the click event on the button.

Why is my snippet returning blank?

Update

I am running the code in a vue app so this is the click event setup

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="reserve_room">Reserve</button>
```

and function

```
reserve_room:function(){
  //alert($(this).closest('td').find('span#one').text());
  alert($(this).parents('tr').find('#one').text());
  },
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Also, how are you calling your jQuery alerts? You say onclick but where's the actual code?

Comment: I chave changed that to a class. <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="reserve_room">Reserve</button>

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.one').text()` should do it

Comment: Might want to update the tags on your question with the Vue stuff. I'm not familiar with it so I don't know if the jQuery answer I gave you still applies. Without the Vue stuff it works though, tested it.

Comment: It doesn't work and vue isn't modifying anything on the html level. Its just ordinary js.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9c012pLo/1/

Comment: That works, but on vue, the event is firing twice and without being inside the method, its not fetching the text inside span at all. But thanks, i can be able to see how i can fix it.